# A continous functional equation from integral problem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am interested in the following math problem:

**Problem.** *Let $f (x) $ is a continuous function at $ [0; \, 1] $ that corresponds to $$4xf(x^2)+3f(1-x)=\sqrt{1-x^2},\;\forall\,x\in [0;\,1].$$
Calculate the integral $ I = \int_0 ^ 1f (x) dx $.*

When solving this problem, if $ F (x) $ is a primitive of $ f (x) $, which will lead to $$2F\left(x^2\right)-3F(1-x)=\frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\arcsin x}{2},$$ then I can calculate the integral easily.

However, my biggest concern is whether or not there exists a function $ F (x) $ that satisfies such a condition.

Comment: Any continuous function has some primitive: that's the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*. You'd be concerned if there exists a continuous $f$ which satisfies your functional equation in the whole of $[0,1]$... But an existence proof is not required (it seems hard at first look).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to compute the primitive of the function, and you don't need to solve the functional equation.

You know that
$$4x f (x^2) + 3 f(1-x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$$
If you integrate in the interval $[0,1]$ you get
$$ \int_0^1 \left( 4x f (x^2) + 3 f(1-x) \right) dx= \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$$
The first integral can be split in the sum of two integrals, while the RHS is simply $\pi /4$ (it's the area of a quarter of a circle of radius $1$). So you have
$$ \int_0^1  4x f (x^2) dx + 3 \int_0^1 f(1-x) dx= \frac{\pi}{4}$$
if you make a change of variables, in the first integral you call $x^2 = t$ and in the second integral you call $1-x=u$ you get
$$2I + 3I = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
which means that $I= \pi /20$.

Comment: As I finished getting the answer you posted it. Nice!